# ANTLR4 comparing syntax trees

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr4

How can I compare two java source code generated AST's in ANTLR4? I have already tried to walk the trees using JavaBaseVisitor and JavaBaseListener, but I can't seem to get what I need from the tree. I'm not interested in method and variable names, only their types. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What is the specific goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to find the similarities between two source codes, based on their syntax trees

Comment: source code plagiarism detection

Comment: "getting types" and "detecting plagiarism" are only vaguely related.  How do you see them connected for your purpose?

Comment: well, if I have two methods, that have the same signature, and similar method body, their syntax trees will be identical up to a point, and almost identical from that point on. If I can define some rules to find similarities from that point on (for example if one method has a for-loop, and the other one has an equivalent while-loop) I can prove that they are copied or not

Comment: If you are going to try to find *equivalent* code in a general way (e.g., for loop that does same thing as while loop), you're going to need a theorem prover and lot of energy.   You could graft that on to the technique I described below; where it compares subtrees to see if they are parametrically similar, simply hand the trees to the equivalence-checker and let it decide yes or no.  If you are going to try to do some ad hoc "equivalence rules", you'll likley get a lot of false positives.

Comment: I'll try to implement what is described in the paper that you provided, thank you for the answers.

Comment: Check out my bio.  You can find a Java Clone detector already built.

Comment: now my problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the antlr4 AST's.Meaning that i don't know how to walk the trees,subtrees, etc. Any idea?

Comment: The documentation doesn't tell you the tree API?

Comment: I can walk the tree, but I can't seem to reach the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if source code B contains code plagiarized (copied?) from code A, it isn't sufficient to simply "compare" ASTs for A and B starting at their roots..  You have to find out what they have in common, and that commonality may be spread across arbitrary subtrees.  This isn't trivial to do.

Here is my 1998 technical paper on how to find cloned code (that is, code which is similar) across a large code base (think "many trees"):

[Clone Detection Using Abstract Syntax Trees (Baxter et al)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/ICSM98.pdf)

This finds subtrees across the code base that differ in a maximum number of variation points (parameters), while still having a minimum threshold of identical tree nodes.

Given just two ASTs for A and B, this will find *near-miss* duplicates of code bits in A, in either A or B.     The paper provides algorithms that you can use on ANTLR (or any other) trees.

If you filter out the parts of A that are similar to other parts of A (they always exist in practice one the programs get past a minimum size), what is left are the parts of A that are similar to B.  Likewise you want to filter out the parts of B that are similar to other parts of B.

You could implement the clone algorithm directly, and then filter detected clones, or you could modify the algorithm slightly to simply not propose clones of A with A, B with B, etc.

As a practical matter, you probably want to do this for two *sets* of trees, A and B, because software often consists of a set of source files.